# extension for Levenshtein distance

Tags: dynamic-programming, edit-distance

I am looking for an extension for Levenshtein distance (Edit distance) for multi dimensional strings (2D and 3D). I am not sure if there is a formal definition for multi dimensional or not, but here is what I am talking about:

**1-D string:** is the regular string

**2-D string:** is something like a list of 1-D strings like

```
dfdsfdsfdsf
dsffgdfdgfdsdaf
dsfdsf
fdgfdgfdg
```

**N-D string:** is list of (N-1)-D strings

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking about?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. **Why** do you want such an extension?

Comment: What do you want to extend it to? To the distance between such lists? What do you say that distance would be?

Comment: A related (but more precise) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399597/edit-distance-between-two-graphs

Comment: @JɛﬀE, I disagree that this should be closed. If the asker knew precisely how to formalize the question, probably they would already have an answer! ... iampat, I think the standard dynamic programming approach should be extendable to comparing $n$-dimensional vectors instead of $1$-dimensional. You would need to define which operations you want (i.e., delete a row/column? delete an element and shift row left?). But then maybe we can define d[i1,j1,i2,j2] to be the min distance when comparing up to coordinate (i1,j1) of the first input and (i2,j2) of the second, and use dynamic programming.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 
I want to use this distance in Kernel machine for learning some structure. In my problem, I need to model Location and Words simultaneously. I think the edit distance for Graphs can be modified for my application